# How to find source hostname with fluentd?

Tags: fluentd

I'm looking for a way to send source_hostname to the fluentd destination server.

I was on logstash but we have agent/server side and we have variables to get the source hostname in the logstash server config file.

I search a similar way to do it with FluentD but the only thing that I find is to set the hostname in the source tag "#{Socket.gethostname}". But in this way i can't use the hostname in the path of the destinatation log file.
Based on source : http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/config-file#embedded-ruby-code

In the server-side, this is why i would like to do :

```
<source>
    type forward
    port 24224
    bind 192.168.245.100
</source>
<match apache.access.*>
    type file
    path /var/log/td-agent/apache2/#{hostname}/access
</match>
<match apache.error.*>
    type file
    path /var/log/td-agent/apache2/#{hostname}/error
</match>
```

Should someone can help me to something like this please ?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

*You can evaluate the Ruby code with #{} in " quoted string.*

So you can change it to,

```
path /var/log/td-agent/apache2/"#{hostname}"/access
```

Refer the docs - http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/config-file#embedded-ruby-code

Comment: this doesn't seem to work in case of path, I'm not sure why. Can you provide a better example?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using record-reformer plugin [here](https://github.com/sonots/fluent-plugin-record-reformer) or forest plugin [here](https://github.com/tagomoris/fluent-plugin-forest)